# How does the NerdDinner example's Dinner.GetRuleViolations function return a list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nerddinner, yield-return

From what I've read,

```
yield return <value>
```

jumps out of the function the moment the line is executed. However, Scott Guthrie's text indicates that

```
var errors = dinner.GetRuleViolations();
```

successfully pulls out a list of all the rule violations even though GetRuleViolations is a long list of

```
if(String.someFunction(text))
    yield return new RuleViolation("Scary message");
if(String.anotherFunction(text))
    yield return new RuleViolation("Another scary message");
```

How does this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't return a list. It returns an `IEnumerable<RuleViolation>`. `yield return` returns a value in an [iterator method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0(VS.80).aspx). An iterator is an easy way to generate a sequence of elements in a method.

Answer (score 3):

See [yield (C# reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx)

> The yield keyword uses what's known as
>   lazy evaluation. What this means
>   practically is that anything following
>   a "yield return" will not be evaluated
>   until it is requested from the
>   enumerator.

Also have a look at Eric Lippert's blog on Iterator Blocks.
[Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/09/iterator-blocks-part-one.aspx)
[Part 2 - Why No Ref or Out Parameters](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/13/iterator-blocks-part-two-why-no-ref-or-out-parameters.aspx)
[Part 3 - Why No yield in finally](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/16/iterator-blocks-part-three-why-no-yield-in-finally.aspx)
[Part 4 - Why No yield in catch](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/16/iterator-blocks-part-three-why-no-yield-in-finally.aspx)
[Part 5 - Push vs Pull](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/23/iterator-blocks-part-five-push-vs-pull.aspx)
[Part 6 - Why no unsafe code](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/27/iterator-blocks-part-six-why-no-unsafe-code.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It works because `yield return` returns a value to an enumerator object, basically automating some plumbing code for you (i.e. it's syntactic sugar).  It doesn't cause the method to return, that would be `yield break`.

More information:

- [`yield` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(VS.80).aspx)
- [Using `yield` for readability...](http://www.ytechie.com/2009/02/using-c-yield-for-readability-and-performance.html)